# Json cant go through webhook call on form submit

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios, webhooks

I have form submit function with axios:

```
const onSub mit = (data) => {
  const webhookUrl = 'MY URL';
  const info = JSON.stringify(data);

   axios({
     method: 'post',
     url: `${webhookUrl}`,
     data: info,
     config: { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } },
   })
     .then(function (response) {
       alert('Message Sent!');
     })
     .catch(function (response) {
       //handle error
       console.log(response);
     });
 };
```

and here is what i get after `JSON.stringify` inside `info`:

```
{"fullname":"Temirlan","email":"test@mail.com","phone":"0179890808","proffesion":false,"message":"test"}
```

This is what i get in my webhook after form is submitted which is wrong:
[image]

However if i use Thunder client and post same data:
[image]

I get it correctly:
[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I used different approach with axios and it worked:

```
let axiosConfig = {
  headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
 },
};
axios
 .post(webhookUrl, info, axiosConfig)
 .then((res) => {
   console.log('RESPONSE RECEIVED: ', res);
 })
 .catch((err) => {
   console.log('AXIOS ERROR: ', err);
 });
```